# listing values in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am doing following

```
List list=new ArrayList();
list.add(new String[] {"1","java"});
model.addAttribute("tagList", list);
```

And in view

```
<form:select path="probTag">
    <form:options items="${tagList}" itemLabel="${tagList[0]}" itemValue="${tagList[1]}"/>
</form:select>
```

but this is not working. What else can be done to solve the problem ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<form:options>` can't work with arrays this way. Use either a class to encapsulate option

```
class Tag {
    public String id;
    public String name;

    public Tag(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

-

```
list.add(new Tag("1","java"));
```

-

```
<form:select path="probTag"> 
    <form:options items="${tagList}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" /> 
</form:select>
```

or iterate over the options manually

```
<form:select path="probTag"> 
    <c:forEach var = "t" items = "${tagList}">
        <form:option value="${t[0]}">${t[1]}</form:option>
    </c:forEach> 
</form:select>
```

Comment: thanks for your response did the same and got my solution thank your very much